# CMD File: translate Windows error message

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, error-handling

Is there a way to retrieve and display the text of a Windows error message inside of a CMD script?

For example, assume MYAPP.EXE returns 2 (ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND). The Windows error message associated with this is:
*"The system cannot find the file specified"*

Can I retrieve and display that within my CMD script? For example,

```
REM mycmd.cmd
MYAPP.EXE
ECHO %ERRORMESSAGE%
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Asumming your program returns a standard windows [system error code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as exit code

```dos
myapp.exe
net helpmsg %errorlevel%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('COPY /y "%sourcedir%\xyz" "%sourcedir%\pol" 2^>^&1') DO SET "copyresult=%%a"

ECHO %ERRORLEVEL% %copyresult%
```

Assuming the source file does not exist, then the error message should be redirected from device 2 (stderr) to device 1 (stdout) and hence be applied by the `for` to `%%a` and thence `copyresult`.

This produces `errorlevel` 1 for the `copy` case.

If you use a non-existent command like `czopy` in place of `copy`, then `errorlevel` will be 9009 but since the output is on two lines,

> 'CzOPY' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

only the last is assigned to `copyresult`